# Call a function inside a React hook is possible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a component like below based on Hooks

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Animated
} from 'react-native';
import CAStyles from '../res/CAStyles';

const CACard = (props ) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.cardTouched}>
        <View style={[styles.cardContainer, CAStyles.ALIGN_CENTER]} width={props.width} height={props.height}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{props.title}</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);



export default CACard
```

I'd like to have own state values and functions inside the hook. But it is throwing syntax error. I know it is possible with Class based components but not sure why it is not possible with Hooks.

My subsequent attempts to find a solution is futile. Can someone help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This component is not based on hooks, it's just a functional component that returns JSX. I think you're misunderstanding what a hook is. The component is not a hook, the component can use hooks. To use hooks, you need to separate out your return statement from the function body. You can then use hooks inside the function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JMadelaine for pointing it out. I changed as below and it all works fine.

```
const CACard = (props ) => {

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.cardTouched}>
        <View style={[styles.cardContainer, CAStyles.ALIGN_CENTER]} width={props.width} height={props.height}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{props.title}</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
    
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As JMadelaine correctly pointed out. You need to write useState inside functional component definition. Restructure your code like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Animated
} from 'react-native';
import CAStyles from '../res/CAStyles';

const CACard = (props) =>{
    const [aStateVar, setAStateVar] = useState(false);

    return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.cardTouched}>
        <View style={[styles.cardContainer, CAStyles.ALIGN_CENTER]} width={props.width} height={props.height}>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{props.title}</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    );

};

export default CACard;
```